# fadeIn page fadeOut page

Tags: javascript, animation, transition, fade

I am having difficulty getting my pages to fadeout on clicking new page links, the pages fade in fine but for some reason the fadeOut is bypassed on existing pages where a link is clicked, I even tried adding a delay before the fadeout and as you can see there is also event.preventDefault yet the default is still initiated. Any help much appreciated..

See example js here:

```
    $(function() {
    $('body').css('display', 'none');
    $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.link').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $('body').delay(1500).fadeOut(1000, newpage);
    });

    function newpage() {

        window.location = newLocation;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare newPage() function before your callback. And You should pass event attribute in click function like this.

```
  function newpage() {
            window.location = newLocation;
    }
    $(function() {
    $('body').css('display', 'none');
    $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.link').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $('body').delay(1500).fadeOut(1000, newpage);
    });
});
```

Comment: don't use `()` on `newpage` when you pass it as reference for the animation callback, you will immediately invoke the function. Alternatively wrap it in an anonymous function

Comment: I tried using the above method and it still does not work, I am wondering if this has anything to do with wordpress as I have made this kind of thing work before on static sites.